quote with image variable
i want to create quote with content, author name, author avatar.
related link: fancy quote with picture
i see this code in above link, and this fuction to call quote:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\definecolor{quotationcolour}{HTML}{F0F0F0}
\definecolor{quotationmarkcolour}{HTML}{1F3F81}

\newcommand{\epiline}{\hrule}

\newcommand{\hugequote}{%
\fontsize{42}{48}\selectfont \color{quotationmarkcolour}\textbf{"}
  \vskip -.6em
}
\newcommand{\epigraph}[2]{%
  \bigskip
  \begin{flushright}
  \colorbox{quotationcolour}{%
    \parbox[t]{.60\textwidth}{%
    \epiline \vskip 1em {\hugequote} \vskip -.5em
    \parindent 2.2em
%    \vspace{1cm}
    #1\begin{flushright}\textsc{#2}\end{flushright}
    \epiline
    }\makebox[0pt][r]{%
       \raisebox{1mm}{%
         \makebox[.6\textwidth][l]{\includegraphics[height=.8cm,width=2cm]{duck}}%
       }%
     }%
  }
  \end{flushright}
  \bigskip
}

\begin{document}
  \epigraph{lalal}{lilili}
\end{document}

How can edit this function: \epigraph{lalal}{lilili} to new fuction with image variable like:
\epigraph{lalal}{lilili}{folder/image.jpgn}
Thank you

I didn't test it but probably changing \newcommand{\epigraph}[2] to \newcommand{\epigraph}[3] and changing \makebox[.6\textwidth][l]{\includegraphics[height=.8cm,width=2cm]{duck}} to \makebox[.6\textwidth][l]{\includegraphics[height=.8cm,width=2cm]{#3}} will be sufficient.

@Marijn worked, thank you
